# Function returns nothing embedded in html, while working in console

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following function. It runs correctly in console, but does not return anything on my website.

(quite new to JS)

Console output:

```js
>       function format_number_euro(number) {
...         let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('nl-NL', {style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'})
...         return formatter.format(number)
...       }
undefined
> format_number_euro(25412)
'€ 25.412,00'
```

Way I am calling it in my web app:

1. Defined the function in my `body` tag:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function format_number_euro(number) {
    let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('nl-NL', {style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'})
    return formatter.format(number)
  }
</script>
```

Then later on, I call it to format numbers:

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <span class="font-weight-bolder display-4 text-dark-75 py-4 pl-5 pr-5">
    <script> format_number_euro( {{ total }} ) </script>
  </span>
</div>
```

`total` variable is coming from my Python code which passes the variable when retrieved from the data (I think this is Jinja?):

```py
@app.route("/summary", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def summary(total):
    return render_template("summary.html", total=total)
```

But this does not return anything. Which mistake am I making here?

Comment: What is `total`? Where's that coming from?

Comment: Good point, added the extra information @Andy

Comment: Does Flask not have an intl library? Why are you attempting to do the formatting with JS on the client-side?

Comment: That is actually a good point, might be a better way to go. @Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert a value into your HTML document, you need to use DOM methods like [Element.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).

For example

```html
<script>
function format_number_euro(number) {
  let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('nl-NL', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR'
  })
  return formatter.format(number)
}
</script>

<div class="card-body">
  <span class="font-weight-bolder display-4 text-dark-75 py-4 pl-5 pr-5">
    <script>
      // Append the text value to this script tag's parent element
      document.currentScript.parentElement.append(format_number_euro(25412))
    </script>
  </span>
</div>
```

See also [Document.currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) and [Node.parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)

Comment: Implemented this, still getting no output.

Comment: @Zal any errors in your browser console? What does the rendered HTML source look like?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: format_number_euro is not defined
    at summary:152` that is weird, since the function is defined @Phil

Comment: It needs to be defined _before_ you attempt to use it (just like it is in my answer)